# dell sc1435 CPU upgrade

Tags: central-processing-unit, dell, upgrade

I have the sc1435 server and it worked well with 2 2374 Opterons (bios 2.2.5). I also tried with 8389 (2.9GHZ) and it works with no problem. Recently came to my hand Operon 8393 (3.1GHZ) so tried to upgrade to this processor but it was unsuccessfu, however it worked fine on one processor. Than i tried to put back my two old 2374s but it didint want to boot with them and similar works fine on one processor.  During boot fans initially slow down than go on max speed. Any idea what it can be ?? Is it possible that 8393 damaged the MB so it work only on one processor now ??

Krzysztof

Comment: after some research I think the temperature sensor collapsed in my server. It still doesn't work on two processors, on one processor works with both fans in full. HW monitor don't show airflow temperature which is shown in my another sc1435. Is it possible to repair it ??

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm now that Opetron 8393 (3.1GHZ) damages main board of  dell sc1435 so don't try it !!! Stick to processors approved by dell.